# How to fix "Workspace Cannot Be Created" in AppC Studio?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I updated appcelerator and now it can not be launched anymore...
How do I change the workspace Location if I can't even launch the program ? It is NOT set to read-only, I checked that.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MfDI.jpg)

Comment: apparently node js was the problem. I solved the problem by entierly removing node js and appcelerator and installing both from scratch. https://medium.com/all-titanium/reinstalling-appcelerator-titanium-on-mac-from-scratch-9a2bb6b9b629#.amdo5617e

Answer (score 0):

You can run `titanium setup` in CLI to change the location of your Workspace : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-35619828_TitaniumCommand-LineInterfaceReference-InstallandConfiguretheCLI

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an issue with the hidden `.meta` folder inside the workspace. You can use the Terminal to delete that folder.

Another option is to rename your workspace folder so that Studio no longer finds it and will ask for a new location. Then after creating that new folder you can move back your apps there.

Answer (score 0):

Your workspace is locked. Delete **.lock** file from your workspace **.metadata** directory.

```
<your_appcelerator_studio_workspace>/.metadata/.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this on windows by selecting the same directory where axway are installed:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Appcelerator Studio

and that's simple.